# Claims of Patent Application WO2017168412A1 are cited from previous research papers

Tags: prior-art, third-party-observation

In reference to the patent: [WO2017168412A1](https://www.google.com/patents/WO2017168412A1)

The  claims of patent application are all void, it is a group of replicated and cited idea from multiple published research papers

The idea of using Metal Rod to insert inside tree to enhance detection of internal acoustic activity has been used before as per below research papers
Similarly relying on acoustic and vibration activity using microphone or accelerometer has been also used before as in below research papers

Similarly using Machine learning to classify the acoustics activity has been used in below paper

Using wireless system/Internet network/Internet of Things in agriculture has been also used before as per below references

**Claims 1/2/3/..../17 ,21  are copied from research papers**

**Paper 1:**

**On the Design of a Bioacoustic Sensor for the Early Detection of the Red Palm Weevil**
Miguel Martínez Rach 1, Héctor Migallón Gomis 1, Otoniel López Granado 1, Manuel Perez Malumbres 1,*  OrcID, Antonio Martí Campoy 2 and Juan José Serrano Martín 2
1
Department of Physics and Computer Science, Miguel Hernandez University, Ave. Universidad s/n-Ed. Alcudia, 03202 Elche, Spain
2
Department of Computer Engineering, Technical University of Valencia, Camino de Vera s/n, 46021 Valencia, Spain
*
Author to whom correspondence should be addressed.
Received: 21 December 2012 / Revised: 25 January 2013 / Accepted: 25 January 2013 / Published: 30 January 2013

Here's [a link](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/23364196)

Here's [a link](http://www.mdpi.com/1424-8220/13/2/1706/pdf)

**Paper 2:**

**Development of a bioacoustic sensor for the early detection of Red Palm Weevil (Rhynchophorus ferrugineus Olivier)**

AbelardoGutiérrezaVicenteRuizaEnriqueMoltóaGervasioTapiabMariadel Mar Téllezb
a
Centro de AgroIngeniería, Instituto Valenciano de Investigaciones Agrarias (IVIA), Ctra. de Moncada a Náquera km. 5, 46113 Moncada, Valencia, Spain
b
Centro IFAPA, Agricultural Research Station of Almería, Junta de Andalucía, Almería, Spain
Received 27 August 2009, Revised 11 January 2010, Accepted 4 February 2010, Available online 12 March 2010.

Here's [a link](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0261219410000256)

**Paper 3:**

**A relative analysis on sound of red palm weevil based on field and lab recordings**
January 2015International Journal of Applied Engineering Research 10(6):5261-5268

Here's [a link](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/283474312_A_relative_analysis_on_sound_of_red_palm_weevil_based_on_field_and_lab_recordings)

**Paper 4:**

**Wireless implementation of mems accelerometer to detect red palm weevil on palms**
Here's [a link](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/261430319_Wireless_implementation_of_mems_accelerometer_to_detect_red_palm_weevil_on_palms)

Here's [a link](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6659402/).

**paper 5:**

**Automatic bioacoustic detection of Rhynchophorus ferrugineus** 
Here's [a link](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/7080308/)

**Paper 6:**

**https://academic.oup.com/ae/article/57/1/30/2462094**

Here's [a link](https://academic.oup.com/ae/article/57/1/30/2462094).

**Paper 7:**
 **Acoustic system for insect detection in plant stems: comparisons of Cephus cinctus in wheat and Metamasius callizona in bromeliads**

Here's [a link](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/43275024_Acoustic_system_for_insect_detection_in_plant_stems_comparisons_of_Cephus_cinctus_in_wheat_and_Metamasius_callizona_in_bromeliads).

**For claims 18/19/20, they are copied from paper:**
**Detection of Wood Boring Insects’ Larvae Based on the Acoustic Signal
Analysis and the Artificial Intelligence Algorithm**
Piotr BILSKI(1), Piotr BOBIŃSKI(1), Adam KRAJEWSKI(2), Piotr WITOMSKI(2)
(1) Institute of Radioelectronics and Multimedia Technology
Faculty of Electronics and Information Technology
Warsaw University of Technology
Nowowiejska 15/19, 00-665 Warsaw, Poland
(received April 18, 2016; accepted October 21, 2016)

Here's [a link](http://acoustics.ippt.gov.pl/index.php/aa/article/view/1777).

All of above papers confirm that this application has no kind of novel or invention

Comment: Then tell the uspto through a “third party observation“

Comment: @DonQuiKong providing a link in an answer or finding a duplicate answered question would be helpful.

Comment: @EricShain yes, true. Don't have one at hand now though.

Comment: The applicant is aware of and referenced many of these papers in the application. Possibly the invention is in the pin designed to be driven into the tree truck.

Comment: @George White
Even Pin has been used in multiple earlier researches as mentioned in paper 1 for example

http://www.mdpi.com/1424-8220/13/2/1706/pdf

Comment: This is the link to the page on the WIPO's site regarding third party observations. http://www.wipo.int/pct/en/faqs/third_party_observations.html. I would be careful upload only documents not cited in the patent already.